# Finding available appointment slots in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to find available time slots for an appointment booking system with the following requirements:

- there may be overlapping appointments, but never more than the specified `capacity`
- the time slots should be resolved to a specified period, for example 15 minutes
- availability depends on the day of week, for example on Mondays 08:00:00 - 12:00:00 and 13:00:00 - 18:00:00
- I need to get time slots in a specified date/time period, for example from 2020-01-01 08:00:00 until 2020-02-01 18:00:00

I just can't get my head around it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My tables look as follows. The last table the output I desire to receive from the query I am looking for.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9be8/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO calendar(id) VALUES(1);

CREATE TABLE appointments (
  id INT,
  calendarid INT,
  startdatetime DATETIME,
  duration TIME
);
INSERT INTO appointments(id,calendarid,startdatetime,duration) VALUES
(1,1,"2020-01-01 09:30:00", "01:00:00"),
(2,1,"2020-01-01 10:00:00", "01:00:00"),
(3,1,"2020-01-01 14:00:00", "00:30:00"),
(4,1,"2020-01-02 08:00:00", "02:00:00"),
(5,1,"2020-01-02 13:00:00", "02:00:00");

CREATE TABLE availability(
  id INT,
  calendarid INT,
  weekday INT,     -- 1 = monday, 7 = sunday
  starttime TIME,
  endtime TIME,
  capacity INT
);
INSERT INTO availability(id,calendarid,weekday,starttime,endtime,capacity) VALUES
(1,1,1,"08:00:00","12:00:00",2),
(2,1,1,"13:00:00","17:00:00",2),
(3,1,2,"08:00:00","12:00:00",2),
(4,1,2,"13:00:00","17:00:00",2),
(5,1,3,"08:00:00","12:00:00",2),
(6,1,3,"13:00:00","17:00:00",2),
(7,1,4,"08:00:00","12:00:00",1),
(8,1,4,"13:00:00","15:00:00",1),
(9,1,5,"08:00:00","12:00:00",2),
(10,1,5,"13:00:00","15:00:00",2);

CREATE TABLE desired_output (
  slot DATETIME
);
-- 2020-01-01 => weekday = 3, capacity = 2, available 08:00:00-12:00:00 and 13:00:00-17:00:00
-- 2020-01-02 => weekday = 4, capacity = 1, available 08:00:00-12:00:00 and 13:00:00-15:00:00
INSERT INTO desired_output(slot) VALUES
("2020-01-01 08:00:00"), -- last possible because at 10:00 there is no capacity left
("2020-01-01 13:00:00"),
("2020-01-01 13:15:00"),
("2020-01-01 13:30:00"),
("2020-01-01 13:45:00"),
("2020-01-01 14:00:00"),
("2020-01-01 14:15:00"),
("2020-01-01 14:30:00"),
("2020-01-01 14:45:00"),
("2020-01-01 15:00:00"),
("2020-01-02 10:00:00");
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM calendar
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9be8/1/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9be8/1/1)**:

```
| id | calendarid |        startdatetime | duration |
|----|------------|----------------------|----------|
|  1 |          1 | 2020-01-01T09:30:00Z | 01:00:00 |
|  2 |          1 | 2020-01-01T10:00:00Z | 01:00:00 |
|  3 |          1 | 2020-01-01T14:00:00Z | 00:30:00 |
|  4 |          1 | 2020-01-02T08:00:00Z | 02:00:00 |
|  5 |          1 | 2020-01-02T13:00:00Z | 02:00:00 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT * FROM availability
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9be8/1/2)**:

```
| id | calendarid | weekday | starttime |  endtime | capacity |
|----|------------|---------|-----------|----------|----------|
|  1 |          1 |       1 |  08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |        2 |
|  2 |          1 |       1 |  13:00:00 | 17:00:00 |        2 |
|  3 |          1 |       2 |  08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |        2 |
|  4 |          1 |       2 |  13:00:00 | 17:00:00 |        2 |
|  5 |          1 |       3 |  08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |        2 |
|  6 |          1 |       3 |  13:00:00 | 17:00:00 |        2 |
|  7 |          1 |       4 |  08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |        1 |
|  8 |          1 |       4 |  13:00:00 | 15:00:00 |        1 |
|  9 |          1 |       5 |  08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |        2 |
| 10 |          1 |       5 |  13:00:00 | 15:00:00 |        2 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- desired parameters
SET 
@search_window_start = "2020-01-01 08:00:00",
@search_window_end = "2020-01-02 18:00:00",
@appointment_duration = "02:00:00",
@slot_size = "00:15:00"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9be8/1/3)**:

**Query 5**:

```
SELECT * FROM desired_output
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db9be8/1/4)**:

```
|                 slot |
|----------------------|
| 2020-01-01T08:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T13:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T13:15:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T13:30:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T13:45:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T14:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T14:15:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T14:30:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T14:45:00Z |
| 2020-01-01T15:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-02T10:00:00Z |
```

Comment: A great and well presented question, but somehow I feel you could have shown a teeny bit more effort in solving it. Anyway, here's a simple tip: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts

Comment: You are right. I came up with several approaches, but always in php. It always ended up in a bunch of nested foreach loops and this got me thinking, if this problem can be solved with SQL alone. What I find most difficult is taking the maximum amount of simultaneous appointments into consideration. So now I am wondering if maybe part of this problem should be solved with the SQL query and part with php? Would you be able to tell which problem to solve where?